# How do I get animations to play one after the other using the Kivy Module

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using the `Clock.schedule_interval` module in kivy and want to get the processes happen one after the other. I'm trying this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
class Process1(Widget):
    def move(self):
         #process 1 occurs with this function
class Process2(Widget):
    def move(self):
         #process 1 occurs with this function

class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        p1 = Process1()
        P2 = Process2()
        p1.add_widget(p2)
        x = Clock.schedule_interval(p1.move,1/60)
        x.cancel()
        y= Clock.schedule_interval(p2.move,1/60)
        y.cancel()
        return p1
if __main__ == '__name__':
    GameApp.run()
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

i havent used kivy too much but i am fairly familiar with animations in tkinter.
what i have used to do is putting the animation in a while loop and when my animation reaches position *x* or/and  *y* it changes path or start another animation.

Also, if you post a link to your full code i would be able to test this out for my self and it would be easier to help you with questions you might have later on